# Hypercomputation & Higher Dimensional Variants of Conway's Game of Life

Tags: reference-request, computer-science, infinity, computational-mathematics, simulation

[Conway's Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) is a simple and important mathematical game with some rules of evolution in a *two dimensional* space. It appears in many subjects in mathematics, artificial intelligence and theoretical computer science.

> **Question:** Are there simulations of this game with similar rules in spaces of higher dimensions ($n\geq 3$)? Does this game have an interesting theory in spaces of infinite dimension? Does it relates to [hypercomputation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomputation) in such a way? Please provide links to animations if there is any.

Comment: For more on hypercomputation see [this article](http://jdh.hamkins.org/ittms/).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for example [Carter Bays' 3D Life](http://www.ibiblio.org/e-notes/Life/Game.htm) which conveniently comes with an online simulator.

You may also be interested in [SmoothLife](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.1567), a *continuous* (though still 2D) generalization of the Life rules (video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJe9H6qS82I)).

Comment: (+1) Really interesting! The last link to the video seems to be corrupted.

Comment: I love SmoothLife especially. Its output resembles "real" cellular life even more closely than the original game.

Comment: @AliSadeghDaghighi: I just clicked on the link and it opened without problems.

Comment: Maybe I have some problem with my browser!